# Timer like functionality for web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to have a timer like functionality so I can call the web api to get the updated records every second?

for example I have this web api

```
[httpget]
public IList<Details> GetUpdates()
{

return details;
}
```

I need to call this api every second so I can display the updated records on my web page.

Comment: You need to call it every second, *from*?  The code doing the calling is more relevant than what it calls.

Comment: you can call the API from JQuery using AJAX. And use setTimeOut to do it repeatedly. https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On front-end Part, you can use Ajax which will call in every **15 minutes** or whatever your requirement based on that you can increase or decrease time.

```
var ajax_call = function() {
  //your jQuery ajax code
};

var interval = 1000 * 60 * Xy; // where Xy is your every Xy minutes

setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```